# Distribution theory and Shannon sampling theorem

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, signal-processing, schwartz-space

Let $C$ denote the Dirac comb distribution and let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the Fourier transform for tempered distributions. Let $x$ be any function in the Schwartz class $\mathcal{S}$ with $X = \mathcal{F}(x)$. Then using the fact that $\mathcal{F}C = C$ (if I understand correctly this is essentially the Poisson summation formula for $\mathcal{S}$), we get $$\mathcal{F}(x \cdot C) = X * C$$ which is a direct proof that the discrete-time Fourier transform of the sampling of $x$ is the periodisation of $X$.

If $X$ is compactly supported on the interval $D = [-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$ then it should be possible to express $X$ as a windowed version of $X * C$ and hence recover the sampling theorem through the inverse Fourier transform. When $x$ is oversampled (i.e. $\operatorname{supp}{X}$ is strictly contained in $D$) we can choose a smooth window $\phi$ supported on $D$, and such a window is in $\mathcal{S}$ so the multiplication $\phi \cdot (X * C)$ is a well-defined tempered distribution. But this is not the case when $\phi$ is the box, which is the window that gives the canonical $\operatorname{sinc}$-interpolation version of the sampling theorem. Is there any way to extend this distributional proof method to the case when $\phi$ is a box, perhaps by some limiting method of taking sharper and sharper smooth boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\comb}{\mathrm{III}} % Dirac comb$
$\newcommand{\FT}{\hat}$
$\newcommand{\eps}{\epsilon}$
$\newcommand{\Scal}{\mathcal{S}}$
$\newcommand{\braket}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$
$\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbf{Z}}$
$\newcommand{\invFT}{\check}$
$\newcommand{\sinc}{\operatorname{sinc}}$
$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\| #1 \right\|}$
$\newcommand{\supp}{\operatorname{supp}}$
$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left| #1 \right|}$
I think I found an answer.

Let $\Scal$ denote the space of Schwarz functions, let $\Scal'$ denote the space of tempered distributions, let $D^n$ denote the $n$-dimensional unit cube, let $\tau_x$ denote the translation map $f \mapsto f(\cdot - x)$ for a function defined on Euclidean space, and let $O_M$ denote the class of smooth functions whose derivatives of all orders are bounded by polynomial growth at infinity. We can show the following:

> Let $x \in O_M$ such that $(x(k))_{k \in \ZZ^n} \in l^1(\ZZ^n)$, and set $X = \FT{x}$ where the latter is interpreted as a tempered distribution.
>
> 1. If $\supp(X)$ is contained in $\left( -\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \right)^n$ then we have the equality of tempered distributions
>    $$
>    x(t) = \sum_{k \in \ZZ^n} x(k) \sinc(t - k).
>    $$
> 2. If $x \in L^1$ and $\supp(X) \subseteq \left[ -\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \right]^n$, then the RHS converges uniformly and in $L^2$ and the equality holds a.e.

Proof: First suppose $X = \FT{x}$ is compactly supported on the closed cube $(1 - \mu)D^n$ where $\mu \in (0, 1)$. Choose $0 < \eps < \mu$ and let $\psi_\eps \in \Scal$ be any real symmetric window function that is equal to 1 on $(1 - \eps)D^n$, supported on $D^n$, and $0 \leq \psi_\eps \leq 1$. For any $\phi \in \Scal$ we have
\begin{align*}
\braket{X, \phi} &= \braket{X, \psi_\eps \cdot \phi} + \braket{X, (1 - \psi_\eps) \cdot \phi}\\
&= \braket{X, \psi_\eps \cdot \phi}\\
&= \braket{X, \sum_{k \in \ZZ^n} \tau_{k}( \psi_\eps \cdot \phi)} \quad \text{since only one of the terms in the sum has support intersecting $(1-\mu)D^n$}\\
&= \braket{X * \comb, \psi_\eps \cdot \phi}\\ 
&= \braket{\psi_\eps \cdot (X * \comb), \phi}\\
\implies X &= \psi_\eps \cdot (X * \comb).
\end{align*}
Taking the inverse Fourier transform gives the equality of distributions
$$
x = \invFT{\psi_\eps} * (x \cdot \comb) = \sum_{k \in \ZZ^n} x(k) \tau_k \invFT{\psi_\eps}.
$$
As $\eps \to 0$, $\psi_\eps$ approaches $\chi_{D^n}$ a.e. and hence in $L^1$ (by the dominated convergence theorem), so its inverse Fourier transform approaches $\sinc(t)$ uniformly. Since the sequence $(x(k))_k$ is in $l^1$, for all $\phi \in \Scal$ we get
$$
\braket{\sum_{k \in \ZZ^n} x(k) \tau_k (\invFT{\psi_\eps} - \sinc), \phi} \leq \sup |\invFT{\psi_\eps} - \sinc| \cdot \norm{\phi}_1 \sum_{k \in \ZZ^n} |x(k)| \xrightarrow{\eps \to 0} 0.
$$
Since $\eps$ was arbitrary, we have
$$
x = \sum_{k \in \ZZ^n} x(k) \tau_k \sinc.
$$
Now suppose that $x \in L^1$, $\{x(k)\}_k \in l^1(\ZZ^n)$ and $\supp(X) = D^n$. Then $X$ is a continuous compactly supported function, so it is in all $L^p$ spaces. Set $\psi_\eps$ as before, and let $X_\eps = \psi_\eps \cdot X, x_\eps = \invFT{X_\eps}$. By the above arguments, $x_\eps = \sum_k x_\eps(k)\sinc(t-k)$ as distributions (RHS sum interpreted in the topology of $\Scal'$). Note that the sequence $\{x_\eps(k)\}_k$ is in $l^2$ because it is the Fourier series coefficient sequence of $X_\eps \in L^2(D^n)$. Also $\{\sinc(\cdot - k)\}_k$ is an orthonormal set in $L^2$, so the RHS sum converges to a function in $L^2$. It also converges pointwise because
$$
\begin{align*}
\abs{\sum_k x_\eps(k)\sinc(t-k)} &\leq \sum_k |x_\eps(k)\sinc(t-k)| \\
&\leq \norm{x_\eps}_{l^2} \norm{\sinc(t - \cdot)}_{l^2} \quad \text{by Cauchy-Schwarz}\\
&< \infty.
\end{align*}
$$
Since the map $L^2 \to \Scal'$ defined by $f \mapsto (\phi \mapsto \int f \phi)$ is injective (see for example theorem 8.15 in Folland's Real Analysis), we must have that
$$
x_\eps = \sum_k x_\eps(k)\sinc(t-k)
$$
pointwise and in $L^2$.

Now set $\tilde x = \sum_k x(k) \sinc(t-k)$. By assumption the RHS sum converges uniformly (M-test) and in $L^2$ (same argument as for $x_\eps$). Then
$$
\begin{align*}
|x - \tilde x| &\leq |x - x_\eps| + |x_\eps - \tilde x| \\
&\leq \norm{x - x_\eps}_\infty + \abs*{\sum_k (x - x_\eps)(k) \sinc(t-k)}\\
&\leq \norm{x - x_\eps}_\infty + \norm{x - x_\eps}_{l^2} \norm{\sinc(t - \cdot)}_{l^2} \quad \text{by Cauchy-Schwarz.}
\end{align*}
$$
By construction $X_\eps \to X$ pointwise and hence in all $L^p$ by the dominated convergence theorem. In particular $X_\eps \to X$ in $L^1$, implying that $x_\eps \to x$ in $L^\infty$ so the first term tends to 0. Further $X_\eps \to X$ in $L^2(D^n)$ implies that $(x_\eps(k))_k \to (x(k))_k$ in $l^2$, so the second term can also be made arbitrarily small. Thus $x = \tilde x$.

Comment: this is amazing. What are some of the applications of this sampling process?